# Comparing two arrays in PHP in random order

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to see if any value in one array exists in another array, and the numbers are in random order.  I have found solutions that don't seem to work when the order of the values is not in exactly the same order.

I have tried `array_intersect`, but this does not work if the number I'm looking for is not in the same order.

```
$array1 = [1,2];
$array2 = [2,3];

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

`$result` is returning false, but I want it to realize that 2 exists in both arrays and return true.

I imagine this has a simple solution, but can't find anything that works.

UPDATE:

Here is the full code (using PHP, Laravel):

```
$student = User::find($id);
$studentLocations = $student->hospital()->pluck('id');
$preceptorLocations = Auth::user()->hospital()->pluck('id');

$result = array_intersect($studentLocations, $preceptorLocations);
```

If if return the results of each:

```
[2] // studentLocations
[1,2] // preceptorLocations
```

But, with full code above I get:

```
"array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array"
```

If I change to `array($student->hospital()->pluck('id'))` for example, it doesn't get an error, doesn't return true, and when I return just the results they are like this:

```
[[2]]
```

Comment: Your code works fine. https://3v4l.org/a7GKI

Comment: When I use an if statement:

'code'
if ($result) {
// do stuff
}
'code'
it doesn't work.

Comment: The code you have posted works fine. If you have code that does have a problem, edit your post to include that code instead.

Comment: `if(count($result)>0)` ?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In the light of the recent edits, your question has also changed completely, which is a sign of bad preparation up front. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidance!

Answer (score 1):

To check if the expected id is in your array:

```
if(in_array($studentLocations, $preceptorLocations)){
    //Your code
}
```

in_array() function checks if a value exists in an array.
Assuming that $studentsLocations is an integer. If it is an array

```
if (!array_diff($studentLocations, $preceptorLocations)) {
    //Your code
};
```

array_diff computes the difference of arrays.

--- UPDATE ---

You can use laravel *intersect()* method to check if there some element of the first collection is present in the second collection. In this case, the return of count function is greather than 0.

```
if (count($studentLocations->intersect($preceptorLocations))>0) {
        //Your code here
}
```

[Laravel 5.8 Collections Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#intersect)

Comment: Sometimes they both are arrays, and they could be [1,2] and [2,3].  The above code does not work in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your PHP script and you might have left a char that might give you other errors. This works:

```
$array1 = [1, 12, 9, 101, 2, 22, 14];
$array2 = [2, 3, 10, 22, 14, 0];

if (is_array($array1) && is_array($array1)) {
    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

    if (sizeof($result) > 0) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $output .= 'Value ' . $value . " is in both arrays.\n";
        }
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry! There is no result!\n";
    }

}else{
    echo "Sorry! One or both of inputs are not in array form!"
}
```

#### Output:

```
string(84) "
Value 2 is in both arrays.
Value 22 is in both arrays.
Value 14 is in both arrays.
"
```

Comment: it is so strange, I still get an "argument 1 is not an array".  But when I return either arrays onto the page they are [1,2] or [2,3].  If I wrap them in array($values), it doesn't return that error, but it also doesn't return true that there are matching values.

Comment: When I `var_dump($studentLocations);` in my Controller (using Laravel), it is ignored.  If I `return $studentLocations` I get `[2,3]`

Comment: `echo` is ignored in the controller, but if I `return $is_array1` or `return @is_array2` I get the errror `"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."`

Comment: Thanks @Emma, unfortunately, var_dump is being ignored in the Controller (I'm not sure why), so the answer doesn't work with my Laravel Controller.  I appreciate your help.  I need sleep, maybe it will work in the monring ;-).

Comment: I had never tried `var_dump` in Laravel until you suggested, and `echo` doesn't do anything in the Controller.  The Controller establishes all the back end stuff before you return values to the view.  But if you `return $values` before a view, it just dumps them onto the browser page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [1,2];
$array2 = [2,3];

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

this prints Array([1] => 2) as keys are preserved with array_intersect

where as if you extract values, you would get a reesult without keys being preserved

```
$result = array_values(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
print_r($result);
```

this prints Array([0] => 2)

Comment: I don't need the values, I need a 'true' when the same number appears in two different arrays (but in a random order).  This doens't work.  I still get a an error that argument 1 is not an array even though if I return the arguments individually they all print like [1,2] or [2,3].

Answer (score 0):

My original post had this problem that was not working, I described in basic terms, and then with actual code.

```
$student = User::find($id);
$studentLocations = $student->hospital()->pluck('id');
$preceptorLocations = Auth::user()->hospital()->pluck('id');

$result = array_intersect($studentLocations, $preceptorLocations);
```

The solution was, in Laravel, `pluck` returns an object.  By adding `toArray()` to the end of the variables, it now works perfectly.

```
$student = User::find($id);
$studentLocations = $student->hospital()->pluck('id')->toArray();
$preceptorLocations = Auth::user()->hospital()->pluck('id')->toArray();

$result = array_intersect($studentLocations, $preceptorLocations);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because laravel giving you `collection` hence it is not an array it is a `Collection`, So you not getting your desired result.
so first convert your `collection` to `array` then pass that array to your `function`
for converting you can use `toArray()` of collection.

```
$studentLocations = $student->hospital()->pluck('id')->toArray();
$preceptorLocations = Auth::user()->hospital()->pluck('id')->->toArray();
```

It should Work.

Comment: Yes, I had just posted this answer just 5 minutes before your comment, you are correct.  I finally figured it out.

Comment: i guess we are typing at the same time.was checking grammar takes time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can completely avoid the use of array_intersect by using a `whereIn()` in your query.

```
$student = User::find($id);
$studentLocations = $student->hospital()->pluck('id')->toArray();
$result = Auth::user()->hospital()->whereIn('id',$studentLocations)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```